# Microsoft Dynamics Online: configure which fields appear on Yammer-enabled entity's form?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, yammer

I have Activity (Task) that is Yammer-enabled. In Yammer layout, when I click on "new task", the form shows up with fields such as "Subject", "Description", "Due", "Priority" and "Owner". The standard form of Task has more fields. How to configure which fields appear on that new Yammer's form?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE1: In Yammer layout, I am able to access Form Editor and I am able to configure all the fields in that layout except one tab, which is the most important for me. It is in the middle of the form  and it is called SOCIAL_PANE_TAB". But I cannot access and edit any fields there.

So, that panel has three buttons: "News", "Activities" and "Notes". When I click on "Activities", two more buttons shows up: "add phone call" and "add task". I click on "add task", and another form shows up, which I am not able to configure and can't find it's configuration page anywhere. I can't find any documentation about it as well

**UPDATE2: A shorter question: How to add a field to ACTIVITIES -> add task Form?**

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Guido, the question is answered here:
https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/112807.aspx#.Uj9wtD9Kvw4

Unfortunately these new forms are not customizable yet.